# ng-Readonly property seems not to work out for input-field

Tags: angular, typescript

I plan to make input-fields not accessible based on date-attributes.

```
<input type="text" ng-readonly="(currentYear<=yearEntry.year && currentMonth<monthEntry.number)" />
```

I am iterating over an array with `ng-template` and so I got the following data:

```
yearEntry.year displays the year (YYYY) for the current entry
monthEntry.number displays the month as a number (1-12) for the current entry
```

In my TS-file of the component I set:

```
 var currentTime = new Date();
 this.currentYear = currentTime.getFullYear();
 this.currentMonth = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
```

But the `input`-field is not being blocked at any rate. I also tried just entering `True` or `false` into `ng-readonly`, did also not do the job for me.

What am I doing wrong on that?

**Edit:**

I tried out like in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly) to bind a value to a checkbox, did also not work out for me!

**Edit2:**

I also tried to use `ng-disabled='false'` and `ng-disabled='true'` instead of `ng-readonly`, but that did not change anything sadly. I tried to do it according to [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-disabled) using the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="all">
<input type="text" ng-disabled="all">
```

and checking the checkbox does nothing for me. Did I miss some kind of dependency or something? In that tutorial it works out..

Comment: Never heard of `ng-readonly`, but `disabled` should work.

Comment: @trichetriche I am going to try, thank you! I edited my post to reference to the documentation

Comment: That's Angular Js, not angular ...

Comment: @trichetriche Okay I thought u'd talk about `ng-disabled`, but you meant the simple `[disabled]`, last thing worked. Does anyone know why the first thing didn't?

Comment: Are you using angular or angular js?

Comment: @trichetriche I am using Angular 7 which is supposed to be Angular then I guess?

Comment: Yup. The documentation you have provided is for Angular JS, which is **not the same as Angular**. Just forget this documentation, and use https://angular.io instead